# Android studio not installing some specific packages

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle, android-jetpack-compose, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I want to install other pack ages apart from the ones that come with compose.
Example:

**For lotties files animation**
`implementation "com.airbnb.android:Lottie:3.7.1"`
And
**For curved bezier bottom app bar**
`implementation"com.etebarian:meow-bottom-navigation:1.3.1"`
It keeps giving error messages from

> CheckDebugAarMetadata
> Downwards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add  `maven {url 'https://jitpack.io' }`

```
dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven {url 'https://jitpack.io' }

    }
}
```

in the `settings.gradle` file. Update or change gradle version.

Answer (score 1):

**@Opeoluwa-Muritala**, I've tried both of the libraries in my Jetpack Compose Project. It's working perfectly fine. Maybe the error is regarding the Gradle cache or the builds cache.
You can try
• Clean and rebuild the project,
• Invalidate & Restart the Android Studio,
If still not works then you can try another option is, close the Android Studio and then rename the '.idea' folder to '.idea_old', and the '.gradle' folder to '.gradle_old' and remove the build folder under the app folder.

Comment: Is there a particular way you installed it or was it the usual way?

Comment: Whenever I get stuck in this type of problem, I try this solution.